# RabbitMQ crashes when entering UI

Tags: rabbitmq

I was testing RabbitMQ using a script, I added 500,000 bindings to different routing keys on an exchange. Only when I try to enter the rabbit's UI - the exchange page, the page fails to load and the rabbit server crashes.

Is this a known issue? Is it a memory problem?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a known issue? Is it a memory problem?

The answers are "No" and "Maybe".

You haven't given basic information like RabbitMQ, Erlang and operating system version. I'm assuming you have a script to add that many bindings.